# I have a question regarding istio rate limit and namespace

Tags: istio, rate-limiting

Unlike the example provided by istio (https://istio.io/v1.3/docs/examples/bookinfo/), deployment, services, gateway, and virtualservice are all created in the namespace of "app" instead of the "default" namespace.

In order to set the rate limit, only the namespace of services in QuotaSpecBinding is changed as below.

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2  
kind: QuotaSpecBinding  
metadata:  
   name: request-count  
   namespace: istio-system  
spec:  
   quotaSpecs:  
   -name: request-count  
     namespace: istio-system  
   services:  
   -name: productpage  
    namespace: app  
   #- service:'*' # Uncomment this to bind *all* services to request-count
```

However, the rate limit does not work when using the app namespace.
It works only in the default namespace.
Is there anything else that needs to be changed for normal operation?

Comment: So as far as I understand you deployed bookinfo application in app namespace and rate-limiting is not working, but you tested it in when it was deployed in default namespace and it was working, correct? Have you [injected](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/#deploying-an-app) app namespace? Did you enable policy enforcement like mentioned in [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/#before-you-begin)? What is your istio version?